# str.split() shortens string in DataFrame cell even after setting maximum column width to None using pd.set_option

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dealing with a bunch of strings with this table formatting:

```
Question Number
Row 1 This would be the topic, question, etc. and sometimes it might be long or short.
Row 2 Second row; 123 
Row 3 Third row; 677
```

I managed to convert these tables into DataFrames using mostly the following:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(tab), sep = '\n', header = None)
df = df[0].str.split(';', expand = True, n = 2)
```

The resulting DataFrame table when printing df would be...

```
                0                 1    2
0 Question Number              None None   
1           Row 1 This would be the None
2           Row 2        Second Row  123
3           Row 3         Third Row  677
```

As you can see one of the cells with the longer string is cut off. I realized that the str.split() line automatically truncates longer strings and tried setting the maximum column width to None using pd.set_options():

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
```

But nothing changes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Since read_fwf() is designed for data with a fixed width, it is automatically separated by spaces, and only the first column is decomposed in df[0]. So, if you specify the delimiting parameter as blank, the long text will become a data frame in units separated by spaces. `df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(tab), delim_whitespace=True, header=None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is actually in [**`read_fwf()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) which doesn't use `sep` and instead parses using fixed widths.

In this case you'd want [**`read_csv()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```py
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(tab), sep='\n', header=None)
df = df[0].str.split(';', expand=True, n=2)

#                                                    0      1
# 0                                    Question Number   None
# 1  Row 1 This would be the topic, question, etc. ...   None
# 2                                   Row 2 Second row    123 
# 3                                    Row 3 Third row    677
```